# When is it appropriate to use set notation outside measure theory?

Tags: notation

Soft question and just starting to learn measure theory. So please be kind, and if you want the question gone, just place a comment.

I got stuck in trying to write on a problem of combinations with replacement (the context not important) the following statement: "Choose $4$ digits from $10$ different options: $(0,9)$".

Straightforward as it is, I started to double-guess myself... Should I have written, $[0,9]$ (closed interval). But, wait, it's not an interval, because it is not on the real line (?): we are choosing just among the integers... What about something like $\{x\in\mathbb N\,|\,0\leq x\leq9\}$. No... So many reasons why not... What about $\{0,9\}$?

So I don't know if the question is worth anyone's time or not, but I don't have an answer.

Comment: Is your question on how best to write the set of natural numbers from $0$ to $9$? I would go with $\{0,1,\cdots,9\}$.

Comment: Not $\{ 0,9 \}$; it is the set with **only** $0$ and $9$.

Comment: I would argue that $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ would make the most sense. Definitely not $\{0,9\}$ as @MauroALLEGRANZA points out.

As for an interval, you could write $[0,9] \cap \mathbb{N}$ I suppose, though this kind of notation is more often used for rational numbers within an interval than integers/naturals.

Comment: @Sloan Am I write in assuming that brackets would imply $\mathbb R$?

Comment: The notation $[n]$ is fairly common for $\{1, 2, \ldots , n\}$ in combinatorics, but any particular notation for a "shift" of this set does not seem very common.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If one were to insist on curly brackets, then, would it be OK to write something completely pedantic like, $\{[0,9]\}$?

Comment: $\{[0,9]\}$, to me, reads as the set with $1$ element, that element being the interval $[0,9]$.

Comment: @Sloan Interval on the real line, right? Nobody would think of integers, correct?

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but $[0,9]$ as a closed interval on $\mathbb{R}$ is the most likely interpretation.

Comment: @Sloan And if you were to read out load in a very exacting manner what your proposed notation at the beginning spells out, would you say that $\{0,1,\cdots,9\}$ is "the ***set*** of natural number from 0 to 9"?

Comment: $[0,9]\cap\Bbb Z$ might be fine as well (or $[0,10)\cap \Bbb Z$)